# Regex : Match digits connected by hyphen or space with lookahead of four digits

Tags: regex

I already have regex pattern in matching digits connected by hyphens or spaces, however I would like to unmatch or have a lookahead of four digits

e.g

1. "123232-453253-535-23" match should be "123232-453253-5"
2. "123-452-3233-2" match should be "123-452-3"

Simply, what I would like to do is to ignore the last four numbers.

My current pattern is

`(\d[ \d-]{3,}\d)(?=[ \d-]{4})`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2qJuT/5)

now this one does the right thing for the example below. when there is no hyphen or space in the last four characters

e.g **123456789** the match is **12345**

however when the string is like this

**1234-5678-9** what I get is **1234-56**

What I'm tring to attain is that I should get the last four digits not the last four characters

**1234-5678-9** the match should be **1234-5** ..

**123 4567 89** the match should be **123 45**

Comment: Remove the space from both character classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
(\d[ \d-]{3,}\d)(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4})
```

Basically, the lookahead is changed so that it matches four (non-capturing) groups of an optional separator and one digit, which I understand is what you are looking for.